# How to disconnect from bad ssh session inside other ssh without disconnecting first ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, remote

I usually have to connect to a border server before reaching the real devices I need inside a foreign network. Sometimes it happens that the device shows some problem and ssh session gets stuck. That is when the magical sequence <kbd>~</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> (this is in my Brazilian layout keyboard, pressing <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>~</kbd> to make the tilde also works) comes in hand and forces the session disconnection. The main problem is that when I'm doing ssh inside ssh the key combination will kill the first ssh connection so I have to do ssh twice to get back to where I was.

Is there any way to kill only the "second level" ssh without killing the "first level"?

Bad example that happens currently:

```
$ ssh usera@border
do login

$ ssh userb@internal
do login

$ do commands
network problem so internal is no longer visible
~ SPACE .

I'm back to my computer
```

Expected example:

```
$ ssh usera@border
do login

$ ssh userb@internal
do login

$ do commands
network problem so internal is no longer visible
<some other magical thing>

Back to border computer
```

On other places we have VPN and router port redirection to access the final devices directly but that is not the case here, I just wonder if there is a way to achieve what I'm asking. I have searched other questions in the site but none that I could find talk directly about this case.

Comment: For me `~.` (after a newline) disconnects and `~~` sends `~` (I learned by typing `~?`). So `~~.` (after a newline) sends `~.` to the inner `ssh` and makes it disconnect. This is not an answer because I have no idea what to do with this SPACE of yours.

Comment: I added keyboard marks to make it more clear and also the otherr way to generate a tilde.

Comment: If you need to press `~~` to generate a single tilde then you *probably* need `~~~~` to generate two, so the inner `ssh` gets one. Therefore try to press `~~~~.`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski the space is probably there because the keyboard layout use `~` as a dead key, it's not sent.